# SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat appears black after Activity is removed by the Android System

Tags: android, android-fragments, settings, android-settings

Solved: I had a frame layout in the xml that contained my NavHostFragment. After removing this FrameLayout, all is shown as it should.

### Original question below:

I have tested my app using the "Don't keep activities" option in developer settings, so the activity is destroyed by the system once the user leaves it. With this option on, if I leave my app while the settings fragment is open, the screen appears black on reopening the app. When I tap the screen, a settings dialog opens. On leaving the dialog, the screen goes black again. When I press the back button, the screen stays black, but if I then leave the app and reopen it, the fragment from which I entered the settings renders normally.

This does not happen if I disable the "Don't keep activities" option, but it will happen when the system destroys the acitivity for other reasons (freeing memory).

Here is some code that seems relevant.

I have my SettingsFragment like this:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey)
}
```

}

And my settings.xml is like this

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:key="rootkey">
<ListPreference
        app:key="buttonpos"
        app:title="@string/setbuttonpos"
        app:summary="@string/setbuttonposdescription"
        app:defaultValue="c"
        app:entries="@array/buttonposkey"
        app:entryValues="@array/buttonpos"/>
<ListPreference
        app:key="levellength"
        app:title="@string/setlevellength"
        app:summary="@string/setlevellengthdescription"
        app:defaultValue="9"
        app:entries="@array/levellengthkey"
        app:entryValues="@array/levellength"/>
// Some other entries here
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Edit: Here is how the settings fragment is opened:

```
    optionsbutton.setOnClickListener {
        NavHostFragment.findNavController(fragment5)
            .navigate(R.id.action_global_settingsFragment)
    }
```

And in the nav_graph.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment" android:name="com.my.app.userinterface.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="SettingsFragment" />
     <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_settingsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/settingsFragment" />
 </fragment>
 </navigation>
```

This is the Main Activity Layout that contains NavHostFragment / fragment5 - after removing the inner FrameLayout, all works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->
<fragment
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragment5"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:keepScreenOn="true" android:translationZ="-10dp"
          android:textColor="#33b5e5"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:textSize="50sp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="@string/dummy_content" android:visibility="visible"/>

<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
                  style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                  android:background="@color/black_overlay" android:translationZ="-10dp"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  tools:ignore="UselessParent" android:visibility="visible">

        <Button android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
                style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:translationZ="-10dp"
                android:text="@string/dummy_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the code that opens the settings fragment. And everything that does fragment transactions along with `if`s around them. The settings screen is most likely not the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you post something fitting as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure *why* it worked. If you can figure that out you can answer the question yourself. Otherwise you can delete it as it's solved and it may invite irrelevant answers.

Comment: I don't know why it worked either, but I'd rather not delete the question either, as neither google nor the search in stackoverflow revealed any answer. If someone else encounters this problem, they might find the question useful, even though it is unclear why exactly it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it worked, but I had a FrameLayout within the xml that contained my NavHostFragment. After removing that FrameLayout, all was shown as it should again.

If you have an explanation why this worked, feel free to post this as an answer and I will accept it.